# How to open pdf file from Documents folder in device Container in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I have downloaded a pdf file from web service. I have found it in device container.My file location is bellow

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E4AFEDC-E3A6-4E33-9021-217A61567597/Documents/myfile.pdf
```

But when i want to open the file from above location then nothing happening. Here is my code..

```
   let pdfView = PDFView()

    pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pdfView)

    pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8180A938-D770-48AE-9FC7-ADE939B1D9FA/Documents/myfile", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

    if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
        pdfView.document = document
    }
```

Please help & suggest me..

Comment: Why don't you open pdf using QL Preview controller?

Comment: @Umar Farooque hello sir, I just download pdf file from web service and view the downloaded pdf file . How to use QL Preview controller

Comment: QL Preview controller can provide you more controls over your pdf including option to share it across other apps. https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are trying to access a file that's clearly not part of the application Bundle, since the Bundle is read-only, so a file downloaded from the internet is not stored in the bundle. Moreover, you supply a full filepath to `Bundle.main.url(forResource:)`, whereas that function only expects a local path to bundled files.

You need to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` instead of `Bundle.url(forResource:)`.

```
let pdfUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8180A938-D770-48AE-9FC7-ADE939B1D9FA/Documents/myfile.pdf")

if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
    pdfView.document = document
}
```

Comment: Hey @David Pasztor, I don't know where I am doing wrong, but it's not working. I followed the code line by line with your modification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Document path with this :

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

if let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first as? NSURL {
    // This is where the database should be in the documents directory
    let finalFileURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myfile.pdf")

    if finalFileURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) {
        // The file already exists, so just return the URL
        return finalFileURL
    }
} else {
    println("Couldn't get documents directory!")
}
```

Comment: Don't use old Foundation types (`NSFileManager` and `NSURL`) when they have native Swift alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 working this code with PDFKit

```
var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent("myfile.pdf") as URL
pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL )
```